# What is arbitrary instance ?Is it same for quicksort and mergesort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Now I know that arbitrary instance is somehow related to algorithm .I mean pivot value in an algorithm. But I don't get flow of how arbitrary instance is defined from algorithm. Also Is it same for mergesort and quicksort since both have same time complexity ?And If different can someone give me arbitrary instance of Quicksort ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you mean by "arbitrary instance"? It seems you are asking a question about choosing pivot values for quicksort? Mergesort and quicksort do NOT have the same Big-O complexity. Quicksort's is actually N^2 because it's unstable, although its average case is N log N like mergesort.

Comment: Arbitrary instance means you just choose any instance first, last, middle, random.

Comment: No I am not asking about choosing for pivot value and I know If we choose random pivot value ,it will be randomize quicksort. And thanks to solve my query about time complexity .But main issue was arbitrary instance value ,which you just said its first,last,middle value .So isn't it same like part of pesudo code where we put conditions ?Or how to represent it . Sorry I checked for quicksort arbitrary value but could not get it.

Answer (score 2):

An arbitrary instance is just a phrase meaning "any valid input", one devoid of any specific detail. For a sorting algorithm, an arbitrary instance might be a list of numbers. Since it is arbitrary, you can't assume, for example, that all the numbers are even, or that it is already sorted, or that all the numbers are less than 1,000. As an arbitrary instance, you can only assume that the list can be sorted.